# What is the best way to represent a graph in real time using the flutter package flutter_charts?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am currently experimenting with **flutter** and **flutter_charts ^0.11.0**.
I am relatively novice in flutter so it might not be as clear as it should.

I am certain that I have to use states, **to make the UI change accordingly to new dataset values**. But where do I put this State logic and how do I handle it? Do I put it directly where I handle the dataset values.

As additional information I am using the TimesSeriesChart, and I am still using a dummy for Dataset Values, along with the GetX package (for state managing), not that it matters much.

**Edit1 Example Code**

**Data Class**

```
class Dummy {
  final DateTime
      time; 
  final int numDummies;

  Dummy(this.time, this.numDummies);
}
```

**Dataset Handling (Static)**

```
List<charts.Series<Dummy, DateTime>> sampleDummyData() {
  final dummy1 = [
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 19), 5),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 26), 10),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 30),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 10), 45),
  ];

  final dummy2 = [
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 19), 30),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 26), 25),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 20),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 10), 25),
  ];

  final dummy3 = [
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 19), 30),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 9, 26), 40),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 30),
    new Dummy(new DateTime(2017, 10, 10), 20),
  ];


  final List<List<Dummy>> data = [
    dummy1, dummy2, dummy3
  ];

  final List<String> names = ["Type1", "Type2", "Type3"];
  final List<Color> lineColors = [
    Green,
    Red,
    Blue
  ];

  final List<charts.Series<Dummy, DateTime>> returnList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    returnList.add(new charts.Series<Dummy, DateTime>(
      id: names[i],
      domainFn: (Dummy dummy, _) => dummy.time,
      measureFn: (Dummy dummy, _) => dummy.numDummies,
      data: data[i],
      seriesColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(lineColors[i]),
      labelAccessorFn: (_, __) => names[i],
    ));
  }

  return returnList;}
```

**TimeSeriesChart Widget**

```
    class DummyTracker extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series<dynamic, DateTime>> seriesList;
  final bool animate;
  
  const DummyTracker({Key? key, required this.seriesList, this.animate = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList, 
      animate: animate,
      behaviors: [
        new charts.SeriesLegend(
          position: charts.BehaviorPosition.end, 
          outsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.startDrawArea,
          entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        
        
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

**Instacing the Widget In the Widget Tree**

```
          Expanded(
            child:Container(
              child:DummyTracker(seriesList: sampleDummyData(), animate: true,),)
```

(**PS:** Some Similar Questions have been Answered, but have also been tagged has being obsolete, since Dart has changed a bit)

Thanks!!

Comment: show us some code that you are stuck on.

Comment: @cas Added it Now! Hope it helps to get where I stand